# How to lock down image on CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to set the image to be locked meaning that i want the images not to be moved able although the website being minimize.

MY CSS :

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/aTOP1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    width:180px;
    height:180px; 
    left: 348px; 
    top: 705px; 
    position: absolute;   
    display: block;

}
```

HTML :

```
<ul class="clearfix">
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP1">星光传奇</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow1"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP2">鬼速战</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow2"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP3">时空之门</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow3"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP4">91GAME</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><div class="header-shadow4"></div></li>
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow5"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP5">暗夜传说</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <div class="header-shadow6"></div>
                    <span class="header_TOP6">KING</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

IMAGE that move :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-shadow{
    background-image: url('../images/aTOP1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    width:180px;
    height:180px; 
    left: 348px; 
    top: 705px; 
    position: fixed;   
    display: block;

}
```

- just change position absolute to fixed.